# Dotnet csproj NETSDK1022 warning with my appsettings json files

Tags: .net

I'm trying to "nest" my appsettings.[environment].json files like this:

[image]

To do this, I do the following, in the csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </Content>

    <Content Include="appsettings.Staging.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </Content>

    <Content Include="appsettings.Production.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now that I've done this, I get the following csproj warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'appsettings.Development.json'; 'appsettings.Production.json'; 'appsettings.Staging.json' Homely.Listings.Apis.UrlStateSystem C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets    213

Now the link in there says I can do:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but this would mean I would need to manually include all the other files, so I'm back at the bad old days of csproj's.

So -> is this the correct way to do NESTED files in the newer csproj SDK format?

Answer (score 1):

It’s because the default SDK such as "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" or Razer contains this part of the content. You can remove it first

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json"/>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json"/>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.secrets.json"/>
 </ItemGroup>
```